# What is the difference of using the same cell or two different cells for backward and forward cells in bidirectional RNN in tensorflow?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

I have this question that I couldn't figured out.
What is the difference between a bidirectional RNN which have two different cells (one for forward and one for backward) and a bidirectional RNN that share the same cell (same cell for backward and forward) ?

here the MWE of the two codes :

1) Using to different cells, on cell in forward, and another in backward.

```
fw_lstm = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(128)
bw_lstm = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(128)
(_, _), (fw_final_state, bw_final_state) = tf.nn.bidirectional_dynamic_rnn(cell_fw=fw_lstm,
                                                                           cell_bw=bw_lstm,
                                                                           inputs=self.inputs,
                                                                           sequence_length=self.length)
```

2) Using the same cell for forward and backward.

```
lstm = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(128)
(_, _), (fw_final_state, bw_final_state) = tf.nn.bidirectional_dynamic_rnn(cell_fw=lstm,
                                                                           cell_bw=lstm,
                                                                           inputs=self.inputs,
                                                                           sequence_length=self.length)
```

I saw these two different codes on the internet, and I am used to declare to different cells, but I want to understand the difference.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that in the first case, you are using different sets of weights to compute forward and backward passes. In the second case, the weights are shared.